# Payroll computation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need you to help me. I have to do a program that calculates the payroll  in Management Sql Server 2014. The program should be something like that:
The salary is the sum of gross salary and paid holidays:  Sal = Gross_ Salary + Paid_Holiday

For the computation of the Paid_ Holiday we need: 
The salary from the previous 6 months:

Sal_6 + Sal_5 + Sal_4 + Sal_3 + Sal_2 + Sal_1 = Base

With Sal_6 = GrossSal_6 + Paid_Holiday_6 ( as i said above)
...
The number of days worked or holiday days from the previous 6 months:

NOdays_6 +  NOdays_5 +  NOdays_4 +  NOdays_3 +  NOdays_2 +  NOdays_1 = SumOfDays

The paid holiday is: Paid_Holiday= BASE/SumOfDays * NOdays.

From the database I have the following tables:

> Entry ( Identry, Gross_Salary, NOdayworked, Date, IDEmplyee )
>
> Employee (IDEmplyee, Name, DateofEmployment)
>
> Holiday ( IDHoliday, StartDate, FinalDate, IDEmployee)

The employee has an seniority certificate with the last 6 salaries from the previous employer.

> Certificate ( IdCertificate, date, Gross_Salary, NOdayworked, Paid_Holiday, NOdays, IDEmployee)

Because I need the last paid holidays and salary to form the gross salary I thought that I should used a temporary table. This table will retain the data from the certificate  and the data from Entry

What I have tried so far is the following stored procedure:

```
create proc payroll
 @idemployee int
as
create table #tmp(  id int identity(1,1) primary key, date1 date, grosssalary money,  idemployee int, nodaysworked int, paidholiday money, noofdays int)
insert into #tmp ( date1 , grosssalary ,  idemployee , nodaysworked , paidholiday , noofdays )
Select Top 6  Date,
Gross_Salary,
IDEmployee,
NOdayworked,
Paid_Holiday,
IDEmployee
 from Certificate 
 WHERE IDEmployee = @idemployee
ORDER BY Date asc
```

And after that I have to take for every paidholiday the last 6 Salary
Paid_Holiday= BASE/SumOfDays * NOdays but I don't know exactly how I should do. I thought about a cursor or something.
PS: If you didn't understand please let me know. My mother tongue is not English ( also this program is not available for all the countries.
The program is valid in Romania)

Comment: please provide some data and output result that you would like to see. thanks

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: For the #tmp I would like the following result: 
ID/ date1 / grosssalary /  idemployee / nodaysworked / paidholiday/ noofdays
1/ 01/03/2018 / 3890/          01/                20/                    100/            2
...

For the variable Paid_Holiday i would like somenthing lthat is following the formula: Paid_Holiday= BASE/SumOfDays * NOdays. For the tables:
Certificate 
IdCertificate, date, Gross_Salary, NOdayworked, Paid_Holiday, NOdays, IDEmployee
01/ 01.01.2018/ 2000/ 21/ 51.20 / 1/ 01
0201.02.2018/ 2000/ 22/ 0 / 0/ 01
...

For the rest of the tables the datas are similar.